# Screen switches to 1024x768 at login

Tags: startup, resolution, screen

Whenever I login, the screen resolution is always set to 1024 x 768. With a 1366 x 768 monitor, I end up with two large black bars on the sides of the screen, and I have to manually set the resolution back to 1366 x 768 via system settings. This does not affect the Ubuntu login screen; it occurs only after I log in. How can I make my computer automatically start up at the correct resolution?

Comment: Which drivers are you using? Proprietary Nvidia/ATI or the open source ones?

Comment: Intel Core intergrated graphics controller

Comment: I tried adding 'xrandr -s 1366x768' to "Startup Applications", but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a script:
Run `gedit ~/.screenmod` and paste

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"xrandr -s 1366x768; exit; exec bash\""
exit 0
```

Save.

Make it executable: `chmod +x ~/.screenmod`

And then put it at startup applications:
[image]

---

**Explanation:**
We first create a file then change it to allow it to run as a script.

The script says:
1) Open the gnome-terminal and then
2) Invoke bash to
3) Run `xrandr -s 1366x768` which will change the screen resolution, and
4) Close after that (`exit`),
5) Execute the commands (`exec bash` see [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/exec-bash-command-248632/)),
6) Close the script without error messages (`exit 0`).

In the [first answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/107885/revisions) I think the problem was that we invoke the start up script with a shortcut `~/` instead of the the absolute path `/home/[username]`. Besides that, to be sure everything works, I decide to also change the script to first open a terminal and then execute what we want instead of just executing `xrandr -s 1366x768`.

Comment: Nope... still at 1024x768 on login. Which makes me suspect the screen is being set at that resolution after the startup programs are run.

Comment: If you run `xrandr -s 1366x768` at terminal does it work?

Comment: I've updated the answer, I think it works now ;-)

Comment: Hey, it works! The screen still starts up at 1024x768, but after about a second, a terminal pops up and the screen flashes back to 1366x768.. 
Good enough for me, but it would be totally great if it were able to just start at 1366x768 ;D

Comment: @treefroginc ya its a hack... here its another one http://forums.bodhilinux.com/index.php?/topic/2536-screen-resolution-making-it-stick/

Comment: @desgua Could you please edit your answer to explain what exact this do? What you tho on 1st answer and your edit? What exit; exec bash\" will do to the other bash command... I can understand some pieces and others not, so I am asking... so others can learn more too. Thanks for the attenttion.

Comment: Done. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: Nice! Deserves a +50.